# Microsoft web installer error "data at the root level"

Tags: web, installation, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to install hdinsight on my windows 7 64 bit OS using hdinsight-preview.exe. It is a web platform installer from Microsoft. Once I gave the custom feed as MSSingleNodeInstaller.msi. I think i am supposed to give an xml file. After this it is throwing an error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1". I tried uninstal and re-install, but no success. Everytime i start it, it throws the same error. Which xml file is it trying to read.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can reset the exe and give a different XML
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer and launch: WebPlatformInstaller.exe /reset

Comment: i tricked the installer by copying a valid xml file in the name MSSingleNodeInstaller.msi. And then it started showing the options. And then I was able to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom feed *XML) is broken as the error is related with XML processing by the webPI application. First check your XML for its integrity and the pass it to installer.

What you can do is launch the offline webpi installer which will download all the xml files and then you can understand the correct XML configuration before passing it.

```
.\webpicmd /offline /products:HDINSIGHT-PREVIEW /Path:c:\a_writable_folder
```

You can learn more on running offline installer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/hdinsight/thread/649f03cc-6d2e-407e-af06-c73faa22a074).